# What rendering should i use for Multivariate Testing between Sublayouts in Sitecore

Tags: rendering, sitecore, sitecore6, multivariate-testing, sublayout

I Have numbers  of sublayouts with them I want perform MVT in Sitecore .So i am not able to find which rendering should i use to perform the test .

I have taken reference of the article

[Multivariate Testing for Sublayouts in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949560/multivariate-testing-for-sublayouts-in-sitecore)

But i want perform MVT between sublayouts .

Thank

Comment: Could you clarify what your end goal is? Do you want to swap one sublayout with another in different scenarios and see which one yields better results?
Also helpful would be some indication as to what you already have so folks can guide you to where you need to get to.

Comment: Hi Jay,
I have 3 sub-layouts with different-2 Thank-you messages. I want display those sub-layouts randomly on the ‘Thank you’ Page layout after submission the ‘lead form’   by the user on ’Lead Page ’ layout.
But I didn’t know which rendering I should use. 
I applied MVT in Marketer form to change them randomly in ‘Lead Page’ layout. By Using the rendering ‘form template’ and it works fine


I am also trying with a single sub-layout with different-2 data-source but it also not works .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using OMS or DMS, so exact steps may be different.  There's a quick thread on the subject on SDN:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=28776

You will need to have different data sources defined for your sublayout, and have the data sources tied to test variables.  From the link above:

> Essentially, you need to change the datasource properties of the XSLT Rendering or Sublayout from Context item to your promotion item. You can do this with or without OMS. But for doing this as you describe and measuring the success of the test variables, follow these steps:
>
> In Marketing Center, create the Multivariate test item. Define the Test Strategy (you can implement your own besides Random or Sticky).
>
> Next, create the Multivariate Test Variables. Define a datasource for each variable. This is an item under your promotional folder. Remember to Name each test variable (name field).
>
> For where the Promotional Sublayout is defined in presentation layout details settings, edit the control properties. In the dialog, select the multivariate test you previously created.
>
> Publish your changes.